# programmatically discover java unlimited encryption

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I have a Java app that requires JCE Unlimited Strength policy files to be installed in order to generate certificates.  However, currently, the system fails silently if the files are not installed, rather than throwing an exception or something.

Is there a programmatic way to check for these files from within the app?  thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if Unlimited Cryptography is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953567/checking-if-unlimited-cryptography-is-available)

Comment: Fails silently? No, it does not fail silently. It throws an exception, but you are somehow swallowing that exception. If you fix your broken exception handling then you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, as GregS points out above, that the program was not failing silently, but swallowing the exception.  The call to `KeyStore.store()` was throwing an `IOException` that I was catching with a generic `catch (Exception e)` farther below.  Once catching the `IOException` separately, the program now works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the cleanest way:

If it is not there your application should throw an Exception, so you could try a small encryption test that is supposed to work and catch that exception.
That's what I do with Bounty Castle.

I suppose you could also check the installed libraries (it looks like the Manisfest within the JAR files contains the strength).

Comment: Actually I would say that catching an exception is the cleanest and most robust way.

Comment: @GregS: agreed, especially since the definition of limited changes from time to time. You might have limited crypto in future versions of Java which are still able to create the key sizes required.