# Check for JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files

Tags: java, jce

I am usure if the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files have been installed correctly in the JVM (because some other part of the system behaves as if they weren't).

Can someone supply a code sample that I can use to check if those files are actually being used by the JVM?

Answer (score 73):

I found that it can be tested with the following code snippet:

```
    int maxKeyLen = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
    System.out.println(maxKeyLen);
```

Without the unlimited strength policy files this results in 128, after they have been installed properly the result is 2147483647.

Comment: Or, in groovy: groovysh -e 'javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")'

Comment: I prefer a slight tweak so you don't have to exit groovy shell:  
    `groovy -e 'println javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")'`

Comment: Works well. Just be sure to import "javax.crypto.Cipher" instead of "com.jcraft.jsch.Cipher" if using JSch.