# Java 8 32-bit - Could not initialize JCE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, 32-bit, jce

I update project JDK to jdk1.8.144_32bit (from 1.7).

But the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.nextSpi(SecretKeyFactory.java:295)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:121)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:160)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.<init>(T4C8TTIdty.java:517)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1603)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2343)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2329)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2071)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1525)
```

Then I installed JCE from Oracle download site:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Nothing change except I'm quite sure that JCE is installed according to such answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13238132

In my scenario:

```
System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES"));
```

return

```
2147483647
```

What's wrong?
Why this environment doesn't work correctly?

I'm working with jdk1.8.144 in 32bit version.
And Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. It wasn't problem with neither JDK nor Eclipse. Simple answer is:

> In our code there is `java.home` variable assigned to custom value.

**Explanation:**

Variable `java.home` points to Java installation directory as said in documentation of [System.getProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--). It is always available.
In normal scenario value of this variable is inferred from JAVA_HOME system variable.

More interesting reading [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45441516/5162026).

But because of some strange configuration of our computers somebody made a decision to set it manually for local test environment. 
And it worked until JDK migration when JDK path has changed.

**Hints for others:**

After JDK upgrade when you are using Eclipse there are several places to check configuration:

1. Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE
2. Project properties -> Java Build Path -> JRE System Library
3. Project properties -> Java Compiler
4. Run Configuration (for example for Maven build run) -> JRE
5. Check [System.getenv()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--) variables if any has strange value.