# How to check java unlimited strength encryption policy on a windows machine

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, encryption, cryptography

My java application I'm testing requires an unlimited strength encryption policy to run properly and I need a way to check if its installed on my machine.

This page provides a lot of ways to check using a java program but no way to do it natively on a windows machine.
[Checking if Unlimited Cryptography is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953567/checking-if-unlimited-cryptography-is-available)

Is there a way to check the policy file on a Windows machine without compiling a small java program and running the program through a batch file?

Comment: Why don't you check the files,i.e. compare checksums, in jre security folder with the files provided by Oracle download site?

Answer (score 1):

A JAR archive can be unzipped and the actual policy files are text readable, so you can evaluate the actual policies themselves (or compare against a known hash as Abhishek recommended above).

Example (unrestricted) `default_local.policy`:

```
$ more default_local.policy
// Country-specific policy file for countries with no limits on crypto strength.
grant {
    // There is no restriction to any algorithms.
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoAllPermission;
};
```

Example (restricted) `default_local.policy`:

```
$ more default_local.policy
// Some countries have import limits on crypto strength. This policy file
// is worldwide importable.

grant {
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "DES", 64;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "DESede", *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC2", "javax.crypto.spec.RC2ParameterSpec", 128;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC4", 128;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC5", 128,
          "javax.crypto.spec.RC5ParameterSpec", *, 12, *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RSA", *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission *, 128;
};
```

The export restrictions are unlikely to change moving forward because of the current state of the [EAR rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States#U.S._export_rules), so you'd be *pretty* safe just doing a `grep` for `CryptoAllPermission` vs. `*, 128;`.