# Exit JVM if Unlimited Encryption Not Installed

Tags: java, assertion, jce

Does anyone know of a clean/elegant way to exit JVM if unlimited encryption is **NOT** installed?  Looking to install a some type of assertion that will exit with clean error when `java` is executed without required jars installed in `<JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/security`

It would be tedious to bake this check in the many Java applications that we deploy.

This question does a good job explaining how to test if unlimited encryption is installed:
[Checking if Unlimited Cryptography is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953567/checking-if-unlimited-cryptography-is-available)

Comment: Simle, make a call to `System.exit(0);` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);`

Comment: Java does not have a facility to install global code, i.e. code that runs whenever *any* Java program is started. You must add code to each program to make the test.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a mechanism either, but was hopeful someone with deep knowledge of JVM had an idea.  You can suspend JVM when remote debugging via `suspend=y`.  Was hopeful an agent or something similar could be added for this.