# FIPS encryption policy API

Tags: java, encryption, jce, fips

How can I find out if unlimited strength policy is being enabled or not in java. 
Are there any API's that are provided by java which can tell the same.

As of now unlimited strength is enabled replacing the policy jars in the jre.
Is there a way to detect this via an API call ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953567/checking-if-unlimited-cryptography-is-available

Comment: Btw, unlimited strength cryptography is enabled by default in the newest Java versions.