# Using unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files without manual installation on application server

Tags: java, encryption, aes, ibm-was

I am going to use a 256 bit key for AES encyption and have the policy files that supports the same. But I don't want to install these files manually at jre/lib/security on server(WAS) as it might break some existing application running on the server.

Packaging the unlimited strength policy jars with my EAR(WEB-INF/lib) would require to change the class loader preference to "PARENT_LAST".

I have following questions :

(a) Is changing the class loader preference the best way out of this situation?
(b) Is it possible that installing "unlimited strength policy" can effect other application in a negative way.

Comment: It will not work that way. You will have to properly modify jre/lib/security contents.

Comment: The chances that the installation of those files may break some existing application is minimal. If you really want to you can use a separate JDK for your server, but be aware that an insecure installation is much more likely to break than one that uses AES-128.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I am not able to accept answer or up vote it

Comment: installing (overwriting) the JCE won't break anything... except that some processes will work then...

there is some "hack" without changing files : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28136100