# How to connect Tomcat with external Java as some security .jar files are not available in Tomcat?

Tags: java, php, tomcat, jar

I have done PHP Java bridge installation using Tomcat, but some security `.jar` files are missing in Tomcat. Security `.jar` files are `US_export_policy.jar` and `local_policy.jar`.

How can I connect external Java with Tomcat or where do I find the above `.jar` files compatible with Tomcat version?

Answer (score -1):

To enable JCE unlimited cryptography (for AES-256, RSA-4096, ...), download the policy zip from the Oracle website for either Java 7 or Java 8.

Extract both local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar and place them under /WEB-INF inside your war file. If you use Maven or Gradle, this means both policy jar files should be put into the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory. Boxfuse will then automatically configure the JRE to use these instead.
Source:[JCE unlimited strength cryptography](https://boxfuse.com/docs/payloads/tomcat)

if you already view this then might be this post helps you
[local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar different with Unlimited Strength Vs Default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959948/local-policy-jar-and-us-export-policy-jar-different-with-unlimited-strength-vs-d)

Comment: Where should I place two security .jar files in tomcat. I have placed files in C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\lib but its not working.