# "handshake_failure" error trying to connect IDEA to Jira

Tags: intellij-idea, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to set up jira as a task server in IDEA IntelliJ.

I am getting `handshake_failure` error when I try to test my connection.

Reading about it in SO and Atlassion forums, I tried several things but none worked:

1. downloading the certificate from jira server and installing it in intellij
2. adding `-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1"` to my `.vmoptions` IDEA startup config file

It happens both to my corporate jira instance and to external public jira servers.

In addition, it also happened with IntelliJ 2016.

Has anyone managed to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server used a cipher that was disabled in my jvm.

In order to fix, I uncommented

```
crypto.policy=unlimited
```

in my jre `<jre-home>\lib\security\java.security`

see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959948/local-policy-jar-and-us-export-policy-jar-different-with-unlimited-strength-vs-d) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758303/problems-connecting-via-https-ssl-through-own-java-client) for more details about security policies