# Java 8 , JCE Unlimited Strength Policy and SSL Handshake over TLS

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, centos, java-8

With Java 8, server which only supports `TLSv1`, it fails to make secure socket connection from cent OS

**Version**

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

**Source**

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by jigar.joshi on 6/10/15.
 */
public class SSLTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SSLSocketFactory f =
                (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("efm.sandbox.vovici.com", 443 );
        try {
            printSocketInfo(socket);
            socket.startHandshake();    
            System.out.println("----------------------------------SUCCESS----------------------------------");

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String m = null;
            while ((m = r.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(m);

            }
            r.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("    Remote address = "
                + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("    Remote port = " + s.getPort());
        System.out.println("    Local socket address = "
                + s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("    Local address = "
                + s.getLocalAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("    Local port = " + s.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("    Need client authentication = "
                + s.getNeedClientAuth());
        SSLSession ss = s.getSession();
        System.out.println("    Cipher suite = " + ss.getCipherSuite());
        System.out.println("    Protocol = " + ss.getProtocol());
    }

}
```

With same version of JVM, it makes handshake successfully on OSX, it fails on centOS, Failure reason is it only tries to use `TLSv1.2` (default in JVM 8) and doesn't try lower protocol

debug notes:

```
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.0=true 

-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=true 

-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false 

-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=false 

-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose
```

**Question:**

- Why it is able to choose `TLSv1` on OSX and not on CentOS?
- How can I tell JVM to use protocols in specific order or if it considers order by the version then how can I tell it to also try with `v1`

**Edit:**

I have unlimited strength JCE policies installed with JRE that is causing this, it works without that so OSX and CentOS difference is gone, How can I still make it work ?

**Edit:**

Output

```
Socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl
    Remote address = efm.sandbox.vovici.com/206.132.29.15
    Remote port = 443
    Local socket address = /10.10.152.143:50376
    Local address = /10.10.152.143
    Local port = 50376
    Need client authentication = false
    Cipher suite = SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
    Protocol = NONE
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at SSLTester.main(SSLTester.java:24)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:980)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:2225)
    at SSLTester.printSocketInfo(SSLTester.java:56)
    at SSLTester.main(SSLTester.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
    ... 5 more
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Comment: What is the exception exactly? Why do you call `startHandshake()` manually? SSLSocket performs a handshake transparently, furthermore, `getSession()` in `printSocketInfo` already initiates a handshake.

Comment: Thanks @apangin, added output, handshaking explicitly can be ignored here I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try limiting the protocols to just `TLSv1` using:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1
```

See this page for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#descPhase2

Hope this helps,

Yuri