# JCE zip file for JDK 9

Tags: java, java-8, jce, java-9

I want to try JDK 9 and I need JCE patched.
Where can I get `JCE zip file for JDK 9`? 
Or can I use the one for JDK 8 ? 
I searched for JCE zip for JDK 9 but am not able to locate it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Update:** Strong cryptography is now enabled out of the box for all current releases of Java 6 - 9. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39889731/3392724

---

I assume with 'JCE zip file' you mean the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files".

Apparently in Java 9 you no longer need a zip, see:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2016-October/014943.html

> Adding, 'Security.setProperty(“crypto.policy”, “unlimited”);' or
>   editing the java.security configuration file will enable unlimited
>   strength.

Additional details:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061842
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/f82971b324f6/src/java.base/share/conf/security/policy/README.txt

Example using code to set the property:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.Security;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
    try {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
      int maxKeyLen = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      System.out.println(maxKeyLen);
    } catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Sad world :(");
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Hello World!
2147483647
Press any key to continue . . .
```

java -version:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+138)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 9-ea+138, mixed mode)
```

**Alternatively**, edit the java.security configuration file in the JRE installation folder:

- Open *<jre9-home>*/conf/security/java.security in your preferred text editor
- Search for the line "crypto.policy=limited"
- Change it to "crypto.policy=unlimited"

Comment: Thanks for the information.  A note: in my installation of Java SE 10.0.1 the "crypto.policy" setting is by default "unlimited".