# Refer java security policies externally

Tags: java, encryption, java-security

I was working with some encryption and SSL handshake errors and I found that the fix was to place new UnlimitedJCEPolicy files in my java7. Two files namely local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar needs to be replaced. I don't have write permissions for java folder in my local machine. How can I refer them externally? I would like to add them in eclipse run configuration in arguments tab.

Comment: are you add your jars to path. maybe it's fixed.

Comment: It's not working. This should be taken by java during VM startup

Comment: your path must refer befor exist path. if you used linux : can you edit ~/.bashrc file ? "export PATH=/home/username/myjarlibrary:$PATH . in windows you can edit PATH enviroment.

Comment: @vahid: Java doesn't use PATH (except for _native_ DLLs on Windows only); for jars it normally uses envvar CLASSPATH _or_ a commandline option. But _crypto providers_ are special; they have to be specifically in the JRE directories, not merely in the classpath.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you. you right. how about -Xbootclasspath/p:my.jar command?

Comment: @vahid: aside from the general caveat that any `-X` may change without notice, I don't know how bootclasspath interacts with lib/ext; they aren't quite the same thing but are in the same area of functionality. Try it and let us know :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link for some more ideas: [How to avoid installing "Unlimited Strength" JCE policy files when deploying an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179672/how-to-avoid-installing-unlimited-strength-jce-policy-files-when-deploying-an)

But I think the easiest way should be get write permission in your local machine, it will save you lots of time

Comment: I was able to hot server by the method mentioned by using reflection. But if I could add those jars with VM arguments, it would be well and good.