# AES-256 encryption in Java without changing policy files

Tags: java, encryption, aes, jce, policyfiles

I am trying to encrypt some data with AES in java.
Till now I have successfully encrypted the data with a 128 bit key.
For 256 bit encryption I need to change my policy files which is not an option for me.
I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492582/5051731) SO Q/A too.
Tried [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) but it seems they don't have any provision for 256 bit keys(
1st question 
[here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions)
 ).
Had a look at [JNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor/tree/master/src/main/java/org/cryptonode/jncryptor). But don't know if its a good source or not.(BouncyCastle is approved by *FIPS*)
Also *Reflection* is not an option since it violates JAVA licence agreement.

So if someone could guide me to the relevant question or share a possible solution I'll be glad.

Comment: Consider rewriting your code to not use the Java Crypto provider API, and use the bouncycastle API directly, e.g. [AESEngine](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESEngine.html). This will remove the check on policy files. Something along the lines of [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher).

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for taking time.
I'm not using Java API for crypto operations. Its just that Bouncy castle does not support 256 bit encryption without the policy files afaik [FAQ](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions).

Comment: That FAQ answer only refers to using BC through the Crypto provider API. Take a look at the example I provided in my previous comment, and try changing the keysize in `cipher.init` from 128 to 256. This will not be affected by the policy files.

Comment: Yeah. Just noticed it. Will implement and check it. Also how should I generate random 256 bit key since Java API does not let me do that.

Comment: My best bet is to use [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: Cool. Will try and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong or insecure about a 128-bit AES key, it is not brute forcible. A 256-bit is not going to provide anymore security, a successful attack will be in another area.

The thing to make sure of is the quality of the key, use a cryptographically secure random number generator (CSPRNG) or derive the key from a really good password with PBKDF2.

Properly authenticate the encryption: encrypt and then MAC.

Use a random IV in CBC mode and do not report padding errors.

Comment: wow.. Thanks for answering. The thing is that the current industry standard of encrypting is **AES with 256 bit key**. Same is the requirement for my project. Anyways i'm using random session key every time.

Comment: Where is that an industry standard? From [NIST Recommendation for Key Management](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57_part1_rev3_general.pdf): January 29, 2016, 4.2.2.1 *AES encrypts and decrypts data in 128-bit blocks, using 128, 192 or 256-bit keys. All three key sizes are considered adequate for Federal Government applications.* AES-128 is comprable to RSA 3072.

Comment: Note: One reason for 256-bit keys in case of quantum computers the keys will still have 256-bit security. OTOH, RSA and EC will become completely broken. Oh, quantum computers of the capabilities required may never become available, much less cost effective in our lifetimes

Comment: Yeah, so read a lot about this last night.
AES-128 can be broken only when you have huge computation power(using quantum computers).
Also, if any method is deviced to break AES-128, it could potentially break AES-256 too.
There is a big hype in industry to have AES-256. Mostly used as a selling point(bigger means better to customers.)

Comment: Thank you for clearing this.
The product on which I'm working has requirements of using AES-256 specifically.