# Is it possible to use sun.security.provider to perform a SHA3-256 hash? If so how?

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple test program that will be run just once that needs to be able to output SHA3-256 hashes for different input strings.  I know that you aren't supposed to use sun.security.* classes directly and I know that BouncyCastle can do SHA3, but I want to use sun.security classes anyways for this test program.

Comment: So what's your question? If you want to use them, use them.

Comment: My question is in the title: Is it possible to use sun.security.provider to perform a SHA3-256 hash? And If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179672/how-to-avoid-installing-unlimited-strength-jce-policy-files-when-deploying-an).  The short answer is that there are "export restrictions" on strong encryption cyphers, so by default Java doesn't have full strength encryption.