# Cannot connect chrome to HttpsServer

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, tls1.2

I've got simple HttpsServer with self-signed certificate installed.
Also "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy" files were installed along with Bouncy Castle security provider.

A simple client succesfully connects to server, **but my chrome browser fails to connect**.

From server logs:

> SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

I checked ciphers suits both on browser and server, they indeed have no suits in common.

Do somebody know how to solve the problem?

PS. I checked JCE unlimited policy is installed and Bouncy castle also installed.
Server is launched with VM options *-Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2*

Comment: If you are using the "right" Java version you don't need JCE Unlimited Strength Policy anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39889731/150978 If it is a public server use https://www.ssllabs.com to test what ciphers are supported.

Comment: @Robert It is a server, launched locally. I got all cipher suits supported by the server and browser. Cipher suits have nothing in common. That's the problem

Comment: Use the latest Java 8 or 9 JRE/JDK then there should be ciphers supported by chrome.

Comment: @Robert Updated to the newest Java 8 version 1.8.0_162, but there is no cipher suits supported by google chrome browser.

Comment: Then the used server is totally defect. Or you misconfigured it. An SSLServerSocket from plain JRE 1.8.0_161 supports a lot of cipher suites that are also supported by Chrome. Do you use an EC or an RSA certificate?

Comment: @Robert Im using DSA algorithm.
Today I tried RSA and it works now! 
Thanks for help!

But Im curious why 2048-bit DSA didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created certificate with the following command:

> keytool -genkey -keystore server.jks -dname -storepass storepass -alias server-test -keypass serverpass

on java 8. By default DSA algorithm is used. Adding *-keyalg RSA* option fixed the issue!