# Illegal keysize using BouncyCastleProdiver while signing PDF with ItextPDF

Tags: java, netbeans, itext, cypher, sha

I am following the examples of this [whitepaper](https://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html)

I made a method that signes the PDF using directly the KeyStore and it works great. the method signs the PDF correctly with no errors whatsoever

Now in the next example, the method is modified to use a .p12 file, and I have that method like this:

```
public void signp12() throws...
{
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(PRIVATE), PASSWORD);
        String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        Proveedor app = new Proveedor();
        app.firmar(SRC, String.format(DEST, 1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS, "test1", "bla bla", PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);
}
```

The method throws this exception

```
exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
java.io.IOException
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.unwrapKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

I read in [this link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com.uy/2014/09/how-to-install-java-cryptography.html) that It can be a problem with the JavaSecurity, so I have tested the maxlengh with `int maxKeyLength = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("SHA");`

And I got that the maximun length is 128.

I followed then the instructions to copy the  local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar extracted from [this file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security then I recompile , I try again and get the same error and I also got the same maxlenght.

Any ideas of what is happening and how can I solve it?

I am using windows7 and JDK8

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179672/how-to-avoid-installing-unlimited-strength-jce-policy-files-when-deploying-an?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Basically the answer where the poster makes a refelction method to remove al restrictions