# Is JCE policy bundled with openjdk 8?

Tags: java, redhat-openjdk

I am trying to package java-1.8.0-openjdk jre and jdk, i am unable to find jce policy for openjdk 8

Where can i find it ?
Can anyone point me the link.

Comment: Do you mean in order to support the unlimited cryptography algorithms?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the following page, it seems that JCE is by default bundled with OpenJDK: https://github.com/open-eid/cdoc4j/wiki/Enabling-Unlimited-Strength-Jurisdiction-Policy.